# Unusual incoming connection?

Tags: vmware, malware, bots

[image]
I have a machine that directly connects to the internet. I have an unusual connection as shown above.

I have not used `VMWare` for a while though. I know that the `exe` file is genuine.

As a quick check, I located that file and checked the `MD5` value. It does not match the one given here: http://www.shouldiblockit.com/vmware-hostd.exe-84fe6a8a8c14a01f9b20ece6d7c42521.aspx

Also, the size is considerable larger than what is mentioned on the site. The site says a few KBs while I have it in MBs.

Is this supposed to be a cause of concern ??

*I was made aware of the fact that this maybe a random sweep rather than a targetted attack*

Comment: Is your VM running a web server? Port 443 is https.  If you question the integrity of that exe, can you reinstall VMware and reboot whatever VM's you have running (if that's even the case)? If this is a home workstation behind a consumer router, nothing should even be reaching port 443 unless you are forwarding ports.

Comment: @Bryan **Is your VM running a web server?** no.
**If you question the integrity of that exe, can you reinstall VMware and reboot whatever VM's you have running (if that's even the case)?** I have nothing running. No VMs at all.
I am not port forwarding. I am directly connected to the internet. No routers in between

Comment: @Bryan I used `MBAM`, `Spyware SnD`, `Windows Malicious Software Removal Tool` in safe mode and found nothing.

Comment: That IP is from China... Unless you are expecting it, I would Block it. http://www.infosniper.net/index.php?ip_address=222.186.34.23&map_source=1&overview_map=1&lang=1&map_type=1&zoom_level=7

Comment: @ScottGoodgame I was told that since I am directly connected to the internet (and nto behind a router), this is not really malicious as MBAM has already blocked it. True ?

Comment: In theory yes, but if I were directly connected I would be really sure  I have everything updated often!